# Tensorflow: how to close tensorboard server

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Once I've started tensorboard server with the command

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/logdir
```

is there a command that explicitly close it or can I just kill it without any harm?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can kill it without any harm! TensorBoard simply reads your log files and generates visualizations based on them in memory, so you don't need to worry about file corruption, etc.

Comment: you can add that you can hit Ctrl+C from the command line to terminate the process

Comment: Ctrl-C does not produce any effect :(

Comment: Ctrl-`\` often kills blocked Python processes when Ctrl-`C` fails.

Answer (score 11):

This command will:

- list all running processes (`ps -e`)
- find the **tensorbroad process** (`grep 'tensorboard'`)
- return the first column i.e. only the pid (`awk '{print $1}'`), to
- terminate it (`kill ...`)

```
kill $(ps -e | grep 'tensorboard' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: While this command may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thanks søren-debois, Amit for the clarification & feedback.

Comment: Here's a supplementary read for anyone who's interested in reading up in depth, especially why `kill -9` is dangerous/redundant here. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryUnix%5Cb%29#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...

Answer (score 10):

In my case, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work. The following works for me:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> halts the on-going TensorBoard process.
2. Check the id of this halted process by typing in the terminal

   `jobs -l`
3. kill this process, otherwise you can't restart TensorBoard with the default port 6006 (of course, you can change the port with `--port=xxxx`)

   `kill -9 #PROCESS_ID`

Answer (score 5):

I **solved** this problem by this way -   *(actually in my ssh, sometimes CTRL+C  don't work properly. Then I use this)*

1. Get the **running tensorboard** process details

   `ps -ef|grep tensorboard`

   > *Sample Output*: `uzzal_x+  4585  4413  0 02:46 pts/4    00:00:01  bin/python /bin/tensorboard --logdir=runs/`
2. **Kill the process** using **pid** (process id)

   `kill -9 <pid>`

   > first number **4585** is my current **pid** for tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

There is a shortcut that is more drastic than <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: there is not that key in my keyboard. Any alternative?

Comment: @KansaiRobot it's suppose to be `CTRL`

Answer (score 1):

You can write this:

```
ps -ef | grep port_number
```

Get the `port` number of the `tensorboard`, then use:

```
kill -9 PortNumber
```

Comment: why did you use `port_number` and `PortNumber` to (presumably) mean the same thing?

Comment: Never `kill -9' http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryUnix%5Cb%29#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...

Answer (score 0):

On windows, use: `taskkill /F /PID <pid>` where `<pid>` is the process ID.